# SQL statement equivalent to ternary operator

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement, case

I would like to create a statement that is equivalent to `(x - y == 0) ? return 0 : return 100` in MySQL. Something that might look like this:

```
SELECT id, [(integer_val - 10 == 0) ? 0 : 100] AS new_val FROM my_table
```

I want to compare an attribute in each row to a certain number, and if the difference between that number and the number in the row is 0, I want it to give me 0, otherwise, I want it to give me 100.

Example:

Applying this query on `my_table` (with 10 being the 'compared to' number):

```
id  |   integer_val
===================
1   10
2   10
3   3
4   9
```

Would return this:

```
id  |   new_val
===================
1   100
2   100
3   0
4   0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why dont you use case statements

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, IF(integer_val = 10, 100, 0) AS new_val 
FROM my_table;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT id, (CASE WHEN integer_val = 10 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS new_val 
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: `IIF(cond, true, false)` for sql server))

Answer (score 4):

Use `case when` statement:

```
select *, (case when integer_val = 10 then 100 else 0 end) as New_Val 
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT id, IF(integer_val - 10 = 0, 0, 100) AS new_val FROM my_table
```

(I stuck with your condition expression, but it can be simplified a bit since `integer_value - 10 = 0` has exactly the same truth value as `integer_value = 10`.)

Note that the `IF` *function* is different from MySQL's `IF` statement used for stored programs.